# Who are the "investors" in Detective Comics #6 & #7?

Tags: comics, dc, batman

In Detective Comics #6 & #7 a group of five (I think) villains (I assume) are shown as keeping their valuables in the Penguin's vaults.  Two of them are referred to in the comic that I can see:

- Mr Combustible (the blue figure on the right of the image)
- The Gas Man (the red figure in the centre of the image)

Who are the other three?  Have they been encountered before?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These are (as described in numerous reviews/Wikias) "second-string villains" who wanted to invest money with Penguin to avoid being killed.

3 of them can be identified with certainty (standing ones); and one can be identified but not 100% certain:

- [Hypnotic](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Hypnotic) (identified by hypnotic spirals in his eyeglasses, and bandanna on his mouth)
- [Mr. Toxic](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Toxic) (aka Gas Man)
- [Mr. Combustible](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Combustible) ([2](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Mister_Combustible_%28Prime_Earth%29))

  They are identified by name in the following 2 panels in Detective Comics #6:

  [image]

  [image]
- One more villain sometimes listed in their company is "Imperceptible Man". He COULD possibly be the guy holding Jill, but I'm skeptical.

  *Reasons to think that guy is NOT "Imperceptible Man":*

  1. His images elsewhere in the comic (where he is dressed and 100% body-invisible) don't seem to match the picture above.

     [image] vs. [image]

  *Reasons to think that guy is indeed "Imperceptible Man":*

  1. The wispy gas-like-translucence could possibly be the artist's way of drawing "Jill got caught by invisible person". If he wasn't drawn that way, we would see her being "held" by empty air - impossible to depict.
  2. Jill is a good martial artist. If she WAS caught by anyone, an invisible guy would be a likely candidate as he could take her by surprise.

     Note that the guy is drawn **naked**. Is there a possible reason to draw a male mook as naked unless it's because he's really invisible and thus being naked would have helped him in sneaking up on Jill?
  3. We see the other 4 guys PLUS the Imperceptible Man (with a matching "100% transparent" pic) **together** elsewhere in the comic (Det.C. #6 page 1 - shown above; and ALSO D.C. #16 and D.C. #19  - the latter is when he is actually named for the first time).

     D.C. #6 page 1 is right before Jill is caught - they likely wouldn't change the 5th member of the thug party that quickly to yet another mook - ONLY to replace him back with original member after that 1 short.

     Also, Mr Imperceptible is listed together with Hypnotic/Toxic/Combustible elsewhere in many issues; and there's no mention EVER of a "guy that looks like a gas-traslucent-Genie". So the pattern seems to indicate that Mr Imperceptible is also a part of the gang in the OP's page.
- The last guy wearing the armor on his head isn't identified at all. Ever. In any DC comic up to #19.

  I checked the names of all characters listed in various sources and he ain't one of them ([[Batman Wikia](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_2_6)], [[ComicVine](http://www.comicvine.com/detective-comics-6-kill-game/4000-313665/)], [[DC Wikia](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_2_6)], and [Comicvine for "Faces of Death"](http://www.comicvine.com/batman-detective-comics-faces-of-death/4050-49469/characters/) and re-read DC. Comics #6,7, 16 and 19 which are the only ones containing the other 3 mooks.

  The other villains listed on Wikia don't match: Mr. Mosaic [has a different look](http://static1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120409213247/marvel_dc/images/thumb/5/51/Mr._mosaic.jpg/200px-Mr._mosaic.jpg), Snakeskin isn't part of "investors" and was injured in prior scene to the one being asked about by exploding gun Jill gave him; Chase/Lark/Trina are women; Smitty was Pog's flunky that Batman interrogated in #6; and not one of investors; Louis Hill was also a [different character Batman interacted with](http://static2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120308171945/batman/images/thumb/f/ff/Louis_Hill.jpg/250px-Louis_Hill.jpg); "George Weaver" was just a disguise for Snakeskin.

---

To answer your separate question, **both ComicVine character pages *and* [Batman Wikia](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_%28Volume_2%29_Issue_6) list the first appearance for all 4 of the named ones as Detective Comics #6.**

Comment: I don't think it's imperceptible man, he's wearing a totally different outfit

Comment: There's no indication that Imperceptible Man's abilities include shape-shifting or illusion, obviously beyond the ability to not be seen.

Comment: It's a big reach.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12585/discussion-between-dvk-and-richard)

Comment: Yup. That's why I chose the wishy washy "He COULD possibly be the guy holding Jill, but I'm skeptical" wording. I deleted my comments and re-edited them into the answer. Note the "naked" part - I explained why "totally diffrerent outfit" makes sense.

Comment: I've awarded (since the clock ran out) but I remain unconvinced that we've correctly identified either the beast man or the man with the metal cloak.